# Functional equation; Find $p(x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations

$p(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, such that:

$$2p(x^2)=p(x^2+1)+(x^2+1)$$

Thus, $$2p(x)=p(x+1)+x+1$$ and $$2p(x-1)=p(x)+x$$
From that, what I did was write p(x) as $$a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_1x+a_0$$, p(x+1) as $$a_n (x+1)^n+a_{n-1}(x+1)^{n-1}+...a_1(x+1)+a_0$$ 
 and use the relations above to try to get things to cancel out, which led me into a bunch of binomial expansions because of the $(x+1)^n$ and $(x-1)^n$.

After still being stuck, I don't know what to do.

What am I missing here?

Comment: $2p(x)=p(x+1)+(x+1)\implies 2p''(x)=p''(x+1)$ .  Comparing lead terms we see that  $p''(x)=0$, so $p(x)$ is linear.  Note:  you could avoid derivatives and just compare lead terms in the original expression if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:   rewrite it as $\;2 \big(p(x) - x-2\big)=p(x+1)-(x+1)-2\,$. Telescoping for $\,n \in \mathbb{N}\,$:

$$
p(n)-n-2 = 2 \big(p(n-1) - (n-1)-2\big) = \ldots = 2^n \big(p(0) - 2\big)
$$

For $\,p\,$ to be a polynomial it is necessary that the $\,2^n\,$ term vanishes, so $\,p(0)=2\,$, then $\,p(x)=\ldots\,$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand the third step you took (going into $2^n(p(0)-2)$). Could you maybe refer me to a source where I can read about that or give me an explanation if it isn't too much of a hassle? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IgorRigolonLa-CavaVeiga To simplify the notation, let $\,q(x)=p(x)-x-2\,$. Then the first line establishes that $\,q(x+1)=2q(x)\,$. Using the same equality with $\,x \mapsto x-1\,$ it follows that $\,q(x)=2q(x-1)\,$, then $q(x-1)=2q(x-2)$ and so on. Putting it all back together i.e. "telescoping":

$$
q(n) = 2 q(n-1) = 2^2 q(n-2)=2^3 q(n-3)=\ldots=2^{n-1}q(1) = 2^n q(0)
$$

Returning to the $\,p(x)\,$ notation, this writes as $\,p(n)-n-2=2^n\big(p(0)-2\big)\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Got another apparent solution:

if    $2p(x)=p(x+1)+(x+1)$, both sides being polynomials:

$$2a_nx^n+2a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+...+2a_1x+2a_0=a_n(x+1)^n+a_{n−1}(x+1)^{n−1}+...+a_1(x+1)+a_0+(x+1)$$

That should mean their coefficients are also equal, so for those of $x^n$:

On the left, that coefficient is $2a_n$. On the right:

$a_n(x+1)^n=a_n(x^n+nx^{n-1}+...+nx+1)$, which leads to

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...+a_n$

Therefore, the coefficient of $x^n$ on the right polynomial is just $a_n$. Since coefficients from both should be equal:

$$2a_n=a_n$$
$$a_n=0$$

That goes all the way until $a_2$, so all that's left is

$$2a_1x+2a_0=a_1(x+1)+a_0+x+1$$
$$2a_1x+2a_0=a_1x+a_1+a_0+x+1$$
$$2a_1x+2a_0=x(a_1+1)+a_1+a_0+1$$

On one side, the coefficient for $x^1$ is $2a_1$, on the other it's ($a_1+1)$

$$2a_1=a_1+1$$
$$a_1=1$$

Bringing the whole equation down to

$$2x+2a_0=2x+(2+a_0)$$
The coefficients for $x^0$ are $2a_0$ and $(2+2a_0)$

$$2a_0=2+a_0$$
$$a_0=2$$

Therefore,

$$p(x)=x+2$$